# comparing current row and previous in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to compare current row and previous row and based on some comparision need to derive a column value. Currently apporach I m following is making two differnt record sets and then use rank function and then by joining rank functions I m able to achiieve this. However, this seems to be tedious apporach, is there a better way to achieve this. I m currently writing query something like below :-

```
    select 
< comparing columns from two record sets and deriving column value> 
              (
        select(<some complex logic>, rank from a) rcdset, 
    (select <some complex logic>, rank +1 from a) rcdset2 where rcdset.rnk = rcdset1.rnk (+)
```

Database - Oracle 10g

Comment: Use **Analytic** functions `LAG/LEAD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LAG(value_expr) OVER (ORDER BY rank_col)` to retrieve the value (value_expr) from previous row (order defined by rank_col), see http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php